# how many operators support in system.linq.dynamic library for dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using `System.Linq.Dynamic` library for generating dynamic where condition on `IQueryable` collection. Can anyone list the list of operation supported by this library? I do only know = and Contains. Can i use "`IN`, `Like`, `Not Like` etc..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is used to create dynamic linq, so I would not expect it to support the sql-operators you mention. Looking at the code it seems to support a subset of the methods in [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).

```
var code = File.ReadAllText("dynamic.cs");
var strings = Regex.Matches(code, "\"(\\w*)\"").Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
var methods = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public 
    | BindingFlags.Static).Select(mi => mi.Name);

string.Join(", ", strings.Intersect(methods)).Dump();
```

Give: Where, Select, OrderBy, OrderByDescending, ThenBy, ThenByDescending, Take, Skip, GroupBy, Any, Count, Min, Max, Concat

**Update**: I now found the *documentation*, LinqSamples\DynamicQuery\Dynamic expression.html, in the download. I think you'll find what you are looking for in the operators-section. (And the above can be confirmed in the IQueryable Extension Methods-section.)

Comment: but i can use =,!= etc. operator. So how come to i know that how many such operator is there?

Answer (score 0):

The System.Linq.Dynamic library looks at operators like == > < >= etc. It can also execute any function that a given property has access to.

Here's System.Linq.Dynamic example for "LIKE"

```
myQueryable.Where( 
    "customer.name.StartsWith(@0) AND customer.lastName.EndsWith(@1)","B","E");
```

This is equivalent to:

```
"select .... from .... WHERE customer.name LIKE 'B%' AND customer.name LIKE '%E'"
```

The library can call any function that System.String has access to in this example. On a side node, it already uses they keyword "IN" and if you want to say "NOT LIKE" just say "!customer.name.StartsWith(...)"